# TypeError: 'Weather' object is not callable

Tags: python, tkinter, base64

I'm very new to programming so please excuse me if I lack the correct terminology.

I'm trying to retrieve an image from a website and post it onto a GUI with tkinter. It works, insofar as it posts the image on the GUI; however it still produces an error as per the title of this post.

The section of code that's causing the error is as follows:

```
    raw_data = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.weather.com.au/act/canberra").read())
    image = raw_data("img", ("class", "si"))[0]
    image = image["src"]
    if image == ("/images/icons/5.gif"):
        URL = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.weather.com.au/images/icons/5.gif").read()
        b64_data = base64.encodestring(URL)
        image = PhotoImage(data = b64_data)
        label = Label(self, image = image).grid(row = 1, column = 2)
        self(image)
```

Narrowed down further it seems line 39 is causing the error.

```
self(image)
```

Full program as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from tkinter import *
import sys
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen
import base64
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Weather(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.configure(bg = "#ededed")
        self.grid()
        self.heading = Label(self, bg = "#ededed", text = "       Temperature      ").grid(row = 0, column = 1, pady = 5)
        self.heading = Label(self, bg = "#ededed", text = "        Picture        ").grid(row = 0, column = 2, pady = 5)

        button = Button(self, bg = "#ededed", text = "Canberra", command = self.canberra_data).grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = EW)

        self.obsVar1 = StringVar()
        label = Label(self, textvariable = self.obsVar1, bg = "#e5e5e5", fg = "#751974").grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        self.obsVar1.set("")

    def canberra_data(self):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.bom.gov.au/act/observations/canberra.shtml").read())
        table = soup.find("table", {"id" : "tCANBERRA"}).tbody("tr", "rowleftcolumn")
        for row in soup("th", {"id" : "obs-station-canberra"}):
            for temp in soup("td", {"headers" : "obs-temp obs-station-canberra"}):                                                                       
               self.obsVar1.set(temp.text)

        raw_data = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.weather.com.au/act/canberra").read())
        image = raw_data("img", ("class", "si"))[0]
        image = image["src"]
        if image == ("/images/icons/5.gif"):
            URL = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.weather.com.au/images/icons/5.gif").read()
            b64_data = base64.encodestring(URL)
            image = PhotoImage(data = b64_data)
            label = Label(self, image = image).grid(row = 1, column = 2)
            self(image)

master = Tk()
master.title("Weather Program")
app = Weather(master)
master.mainloop()
```

I should add that if the website has updated its image and it's no longer '5.gif' (being a weather icon it's highly likely) then a picture won't show up.

Any help or direction would be much appreciated. I've looked high and low but to no avail. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to mark line 39 please???

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post so I'm still learning the ropes. How do you mark a line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call an object like a function. When you say `self(image)` in your code, you are trying to call the object. If you want to do that you need to implement the `__call__` method. However, I have coded your example and made changes to it. Kindly run it. I hope it helps

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from tkinter import *
import sys
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen
import base64
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Weather(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.configure(bg = "#ededed")
        self.grid()
        self.heading = Label(self, bg = "#ededed", text = "       Temperature      ").grid(row = 0, column = 1, pady = 5)
        self.heading = Label(self, bg = "#ededed", text = "        Picture        ").grid(row = 0, column = 2, pady = 5)

        button = Button(self, bg = "#ededed", text = "Canberra", command = self.canberra_data).grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = EW)

        self.obsVar1 = StringVar()
        label = Label(self, textvariable = self.obsVar1, bg = "#e5e5e5", fg = "#751974").grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        self.obsVar1.set("")

    def canberra_data(self):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.bom.gov.au/act/observations/canberra.shtml").read())
        table = soup.find("table", {"id" : "tCANBERRA"}).tbody("tr", "rowleftcolumn")
        for row in soup("th", {"id" : "obs-station-canberra"}):
            for temp in soup("td", {"headers" : "obs-temp obs-station-canberra"}):
               self.obsVar1.set(temp.text)

        raw_data = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.weather.com.au/act/canberra").read())
        image = raw_data("img", ("class", "si"))[0]
        image = image["src"]
        if image == ("/images/icons/5.gif"):
            URL = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.weather.com.au/images/icons/5.gif").read()
            b64_data = base64.encodestring(URL)
            image = PhotoImage(data = b64_data)
            label = Label(self, image = image)
            label.image = image
            label.grid(row=1,column=2)

master = Tk()
master.title("Weather Program")
app = Weather(master)
master.mainloop()
```

The diff of your and my version is as follows:

```
<             label = Label(self, image = image).grid(row = 1, column = 2)
<             self(image)
---
>             label = Label(self, image = image)
>             label.image = image
>             label.grid(row=1,column=2)
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! What an awesome resource this is. I'm still a bit hazy with the concept of objects but in time I'll learn.

Comment: I'm more than happy that it's working now; however I would like ideally the label = Label(self, image = image).grid(row=1, column=2) to be sitting within the def __init__ function, as I have for the other labels. Is this possible with my program? It's an improvement that I'd like to implement so I don't have to repeat the label positioning in grid. I'd need to store the image in a variable as I have for the temperature; however I haven't worked out how to do that. Any suggestions would again be much  appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The line containing self(image) is not correct. The 'self' is not a class, it's an object. So, if you want to create an object of type Weather and pass something to its constructor, just call Weather(image).

Comment: I did try that, but unfortunately it still produces an error: 
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_w'

Comment: It seams the new error is related to constructor of Frame class. Is is possible to show me full stack trace of error. You should look at Frame constructor code to see what is wrong.

Comment: The full error is quite long (21 lines). I'm not sure if this will help but it starts with: Exception in Tkinter callback. It seems to be pointing at the tkinter __init__.py file. The last few lines are:   

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2070, in _setup
    if master._w=='.':
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_w'

Comment: It means that this error is not related to your original post. It's a tkinter related error. Post another question with tkinter tag to get related answers. I am not a tkinter expert. Sorry.

Comment: I'm not so sure it's a tkinter problem because if I take away the class Weather(Frame): and the def functions it works. But I need them there to separate data for each city. Thanks anyway.